# Why "findChessboardCorners" function is returning false

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using Opencv "findChessboardCorners" function to find corners of chess board, but I am getting false as a returned value from "findChessboardCorners" function.

Following is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<vector<Point2f>> imagePoints;    
    Mat view;
    bool found; 
    vector<Point2f> pointBuf;
    Size boardSize;            // The size of the board -> Number of items by width and height  
    boardSize.width = 75;
    boardSize.height = 49;

    view = cv::imread("FraunhoferChessBoard.jpeg"); 
    namedWindow("Original Image", WINDOW_NORMAL);// Create a window for display.
    imshow("Original Image", view);

    found = findChessboardCorners(view, boardSize, pointBuf,
             CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK | CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);

    if (found)
    {
        cout << "Corners of chess board detected";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Corners of chess board not detected";
    }
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect return value from "findChessboardCorners" function to be true whereas I am getting false.

Please explain me where have I made mistake ?

Many thanks :)[image]

Comment: Try to add the flags: `CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + CV_CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK + CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function didn't find the pattern in your image and this is why it returns false. Maybe the exact same code works with a different image.
I cannot directly answer to why this function did not find the pattern inside your image, but I would recommend different approaches to be less sensitive to the noise, so that the algorithm could detect properly your corners:
- Use `findChessboardCornersSB` instead of `findChessboardCorners`. According to the documentation it is more robust to noise and works faster for large images like yours. That's probably what you are looking for. I tried and with python it works properly with the image you posted. See the result below. 
- Change the pattern shapes as shown in the doc for `findChessboardCornersSB`.
- Use less and bigger squares in your pattern. It's not helping to have so many squares.

For the next step you will need to use a non-symmetrical pattern. If your top-left square is white then the bottom right has to be black.

If you have additional problems with the square pattern, you could also change your approach using corners and switch to the circle pattern. All functions are available in opencv. In my case it worked better. See `findCirclesGrid`. If you use this method, you can run the "BlobDetector" to check how each circle is detected and configure some parameters to improve the accuracy.

Hope this helps!

[image]
EDIT:
Here is the python code to make it work from the downloaded image.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
img_small = cv2.resize(img, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))

found, corners = cv2.findChessboardCornersSB(img_small, (75, 49), flags=0)

plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img_small, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), cmap='gray')
plt.scatter(corners[:, 0, 0], corners[:, 0, 1])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time. I have tried "findChessboardCornersSB(view, boardSize, pointBuf, CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE | CALIB_CB_EXHAUSTIVE | CALIB_CB_ACCURACY);" function to find coordinates of squares in picture, I have attached above but still I am not able to find corners of square boxes  using C++ code. Did you also do any change in above attached image before running "findChessboardCornersSB(view, boardSize, pointBuf, CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE | CALIB_CB_EXHAUSTIVE | CALIB_CB_ACCURACY);" algo? Thank you:)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't try with your flags. With your flags it doesn't work indeed. With 0 it worked.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you think that you don't need help anymore regarding this point :)

Comment: @87VN0...I have tried your method with following given picture again but could able to find corners of square boxes this time. Can you please once again inform me what can I do to improve this situation...Many thanks ...:)